# How to call on text from a textbox to set a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a bit of a predicament. I am trying to run a variable on a loop so that it can change the loop. Here is the code that I have at the present time.

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" id="Variable"><P>
</FORM>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("Variable").value = i;
var i=5;
for (i=0;i<=5;i++)
{
document.write(" " + i);
document.write("<br />");
}
</script>
```

I am trying to call upon the text in the textbox from the form in order to define var i. I would also like to point out that I am no master of HTML, and if you see that I have done this all wrong, feel free to tell me that it cannot be done.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean something like this:

```
var count = parseInt(document.getElementById("Variable").value, 10);
var i;
for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    // ...do something...
}
```

What that does:

1. Looks up the element by its ID (you already had that): `document.getElementById("Variable')`.
2. Retrieves the value of its `value` property, which is a string.
3. Converts the string into an number via `parseInt`, using decimal (as opposed to octal or hexadecimal).
4. Loops from zero (inclusive) to that number (exclusive).

Note that you can't use `document.write` after the main parse (initial load) of the page, and you probably don't want to use the value from a form field *before* the main parse of the page is complete, so you probably won't be doing `document.write` here. You might set the `innerHTML` of an element, something like that.

Re my "...you can't use `document.write` after the main parse...": Technically, you *can*, but you'll completely *replace* the page rather than just adding to it.

Re my "...and you probably don't want to use the value from a form field *before* the main parse...is complete...": You *can*, though, as long as the form field is above the script in the page markup. I did literally mean you probably don't *want* to, presumably you want the user to enter some value first.

---

**Update**: Here's a more complete example, with a live copy to play with:

```
var element, value, count, i;

element = document.getElementById("Variable");
if (!element) {
  display("Element 'Variable' not found.");
}
else {
  value = element.value;
  count = parseInt(value, 10);
  if (isNaN(count)) {
    display("'" + value + "' is not numeric");
  }
  else {
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        display("Loop " + i);
    }
  }
}

function display(msg) {
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  p.innerHTML = msg;
  document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

[Live copy](http://jsbin.com/ewaze4), the `display` function is obviously a bit of a placeholder for whatever it is you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand your exact question. but I guess this is your solution :

```
<FORM NAME="myform" ACTION="" METHOD="GET">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" id="Variable">
<input type="button" value="run" onclick="renderIt()" />
<P>
</FORM>

<script type="text/javascript">
function renderIt()
{
var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("Variable").value);
for (i=0;i<=max;i++)
{
document.write(" " + i);
document.write("<br />");
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: That will tear down the page entirely and replace it (which may or may not be what they wanted, just flagging it up). (I took the liberty of a *tiny* bugfix as well, just changed `m` to `max` in the limit part of the `for` loop.)